# How to disable previous items in a ListView

Tags: android, listview, custom-adapter

I am trying to develop an activity where there is a custom `listView` made out of `CustomAdapter`.

The list consists of a `TextView` and an `EditText`. The `EditText` when `clicked`, it auto fetches the system time.

**What I want** is when a particular `EditText` is filled, I want all the previous(above) list items in the sequence to be disabled.

So far, I have tried using `isEnabled()` and `areAllItemsEnabled()` functions returning respective boolean values using position, but however didn’t work.

Please help me achieve the above.
[image]

Thanks.

This is my CustomAdapter Class

```html
public class SelectStnListByRoute extends BaseAdapter implements View.OnClickListener {
    Context context;
    ArrayList<StnNames> stnList;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = null;
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    private int mLastClicked;

    public SelectStnListByRoute(Context context, ArrayList<StnNames> stnList) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        this.stnList = stnList;
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return stnList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return stnList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return stnList.indexOf(getItem(position));
    }

    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
        if(position==position){
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        int type = getItemViewType(position);
        StnNames stnDetails = stnList.get(position);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.footplate_custome_layout, null);
            viewHolder.txtStnNAme = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtStnCode);
            viewHolder.txtStnArr = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtArrivalTime);
            viewHolder.txtStnDep = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtDepTime);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            viewHolder.txtStnArr.setTag(stnDetails);
            viewHolder.txtStnDep.setTag(stnDetails);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            viewHolder.txtStnArr.setTag(stnDetails);
            viewHolder.txtStnDep.setTag(stnDetails);
        }
        viewHolder.txtStnNAme.setText(stnDetails.getStnCode());

          viewHolder.txtStnArr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.e("Position: " , String.valueOf(position)); //Here I am getting the position of the row item clicked, where should I put the Onclick false for disabling all of the above fields using the position?
        }
    });
        viewHolder.txtStnDep.setOnClickListener(this);
        viewHolder.txtStnArr = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtArrivalTime);
        if (stnDetails.getArrivalTime() != null) {
            viewHolder.txtStnArr.setText(stnDetails.getArrivalTime());
        } else {
            viewHolder.txtStnArr.setText("");
        }


        if (stnDetails.getDeptTime() != null) {
            viewHolder.txtStnDep.setText(stnDetails.getDeptTime());
        } else {
            viewHolder.txtStnDep.setText("");
        } 
        return convertView;
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        TextView txtStnNAme, txtStnArr, txtStnDep;
        int ref;
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int id = view.getId();

        switch (id) {
            case txtArrivalTime:
                TextView textViewArrVal = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtArrivalTime);
                textViewArrVal.setClickable(false);
                StnNames listItemsArrr = (StnNames) textViewArrVal.getTag();
                if (listItemsArrr.getArrivalTime() != getCurrentTime()) {
                    listItemsArrr.setArrivalTime(getCurrentTime());
                    if (listItemsArrr.getArrivalTime() != null) {
                        int position = textViewArrVal.getSelectionStart();
                        textViewArrVal.setText(listItemsArrr.getArrivalTime());

                    } else {
                        textViewArrVal.setText("");
                    }
                }
                break;
            case txtDepTime:
                TextView textViewDepVal = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtDepTime);
                StnNames listItemsDepp = (StnNames) textViewDepVal.getTag();
                if (listItemsDepp.getDeptTime() != getCurrentTime()) {
                    listItemsDepp.setDeptTime(getCurrentTime());
                    if (listItemsDepp.getDeptTime() != null) {
                        textViewDepVal.setText(listItemsDepp.getDeptTime());
                    } else {
                        textViewDepVal.setText("");
                    }
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

    }
    public String getCurrentTime(){

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat mdformat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        String arrDate = mdformat.format(calendar.getTime());
        return arrDate;
    }

}
```

Comment: show your code ? what have you tried ?

Comment: put your adapter code so we can tell you what must you do

Comment: @sushildlh 
I have edited the question and added my customAdapter class code above

Comment: @Fakher Please Check I have edited with the code

Comment: ok its easy all you have to do is make ka call back on click listener.! and display date when ever click on list item.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this as below mentioned -:

You need to store the position of clicked button was. So initialize a variable in your class

```
int mButtonSelected = -1;
```

**EDIT 1.**

Then make a change to your `isEnabled` method

```
 @Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    if(position<mButtonSelected){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

That will work it if any other button was clicked. but you have to do that in your `onClick`

```
mButtonSelected = position;
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Let me it worked or not

**EDIT**

see below changes in your code-:

```
public class SelectStnListByRoute extends BaseAdapter {
Context context;
ArrayList<StnNames> stnList;
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = null;
ViewHolder viewHolder;
private int mLastClicked;
private SQLiteDB sqLiteDB;
int mArrivalSelected = -1;
int mDepartSelected = -1;

public SelectStnListByRoute(Context context, ArrayList<StnNames> stnList) {
    super();
    this.context = context;
    this.stnList = stnList;
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    sqLiteDB = new SQLiteDB(context);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return stnList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return stnList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return stnList.indexOf(getItem(position));
}

public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 1;
}

@Override
public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    if (position <= mArrivalSelected) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public boolean isEnabledd(int position) {
    if (position <= mDepartSelected) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    int type = getItemViewType(position);
    StnNames stnDetails = stnList.get(position);
    viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.footplate_custome_layout, null);
        viewHolder.txtStnNAme = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtStnCode);
        viewHolder.txtStnArr = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtArrivalTime);
        viewHolder.txtStnDep = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtDepTime);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        viewHolder.txtStnArr.setTag(stnDetails);
        viewHolder.txtStnDep.setTag(stnDetails);


    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        viewHolder.txtStnArr.setTag(stnDetails);
        viewHolder.txtStnDep.setTag(stnDetails);

    }


    viewHolder.txtStnNAme.setText(stnDetails.getStnCode());
    if (!isEnabled(position)) {
        if (position <= mArrivalSelected) {
            viewHolder.txtStnArr.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffa500"));
            viewHolder.txtStnArr.setEnabled(false);
            if (position < mArrivalSelected) {
                viewHolder.txtStnDep.setEnabled(false);
                viewHolder.txtStnDep.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffa500"));
            }
        }
    } else {
        viewHolder.txtStnArr.setEnabled(true);
        viewHolder.txtStnDep.setEnabled(true);
        viewHolder.txtStnArr.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#b4b4b4"));
        viewHolder.txtStnDep.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#b4b4b4"));
    }
    viewHolder.txtStnArr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.e("Position: ", String.valueOf(position));
            mArrivalSelected = position;
            arrivalClick(view);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
    if (!isEnabledd(position)) {
        if (position <= mDepartSelected) {
            viewHolder.txtStnArr.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffa500"));
            viewHolder.txtStnDep.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffa500"));
            viewHolder.txtStnArr.setEnabled(false);
            viewHolder.txtStnDep.setEnabled(false);
        } else {
            viewHolder.txtStnArr.setEnabled(true);
            viewHolder.txtStnDep.setEnabled(true);
            viewHolder.txtStnArr.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#b4b4b4"));
            viewHolder.txtStnDep.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#b4b4b4"));
        }
    }
    viewHolder.txtStnDep.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.e("Position: ", String.valueOf(position));
            mDepartSelected = position;
            departureClick(view);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
    viewHolder.txtStnArr = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtArrivalTime);
    if (stnDetails.getArrivalTime() != null) {
        viewHolder.txtStnArr.setText(stnDetails.getArrivalTime());
    } else {
        viewHolder.txtStnArr.setText("");
    }


    if (stnDetails.getDeptTime() != null) {
        viewHolder.txtStnDep.setText(stnDetails.getDeptTime());
    } else {
        viewHolder.txtStnDep.setText("");
    }

    return convertView;
}

class ViewHolder {
    TextView txtStnNAme, txtStnArr, txtStnDep;
    StnNames pos;
    int ref;
}

public void arrivalClick(View view) {
    TextView textViewArrVal = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtArrivalTime);

    StnNames listItemsArrr = (StnNames) textViewArrVal.getTag();
    if (listItemsArrr.getArrivalTime() != getCurrentTime()) {
        listItemsArrr.setArrivalTime(getCurrentTime());
        int stnId = listItemsArrr.getStnId();
        String arrClick = "arrival";
        String upSideKm = listItemsArrr.getStnUpsideKm();
        String downsideKm = listItemsArrr.getStnDownSideKm();
        String arrTime = getCurrentTime();
           /*     sqLiteDB.open();
               *//* long abc = sqLiteDB.insertJourneySchedule(stnId,arrTime,"",userId,journeyId,latitute,longitute,journyDate,arrClick);*//*
               *//* long abcd = sqLiteDB.updateJourneySchedule(stnId,arrTime,"",userId,journeyId,latitute,longitute,journyDate,arrClick,downsideKm,upSideKm);
                Log.e("arrclick",String.valueOf(abcd));*//*
                sqLiteDB.close();*/
        if (listItemsArrr.getArrivalTime() != null) {
            int position = textViewArrVal.getSelectionStart();
            textViewArrVal.setText(listItemsArrr.getArrivalTime());

        } else {
            textViewArrVal.setText("");
        }
    }
}

public void departureClick(View view) {
    TextView textViewDepVal = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtDepTime);
    StnNames listItemsDepp = (StnNames) textViewDepVal.getTag();
    if (listItemsDepp.getDeptTime() != getCurrentTime()) {
        listItemsDepp.setDeptTime(getCurrentTime());
        String depTime = getCurrentTime();
        int stnId = listItemsDepp.getStnId();
        String depClick = "departure";
        String upSideKm = listItemsDepp.getStnUpsideKm();
        String downsideKm = listItemsDepp.getStnDownSideKm();
        sqLiteDB.open();
                /*long abc = sqLiteDB.insertJourneySchedule(stnId,"",depTime,userId,journeyId,latitute,longitute,journyDate,depClick);*/
                /*long abcd = sqLiteDB.updateJourneySchedule(stnId,"",depTime,userId,journeyId,latitute,longitute,journyDate,depClick,downsideKm,upSideKm);
                Log.e("depclick",String.valueOf(abcd));*/
        sqLiteDB.close();
        if (listItemsDepp.getDeptTime() != null) {
            textViewDepVal.setText(listItemsDepp.getDeptTime());
        } else {
            textViewDepVal.setText("");
        }
    }
}



public String getCurrentTime() {

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat mdformat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    String arrDate = mdformat.format(calendar.getTime());
    return arrDate;
}

}
```

Comment: mButtonSelected = position; 

This is showing not a statement in onClick()

Comment: now check i made some changes to your code  try this @An08NY

Comment: Works like a charm..!! Much appreciated!

Comment: There is a new problem. Whenever I select a field and scroll the listView, the bottom fields are disabled too. I am not able to get a workaround for that. What can be the problem?

Comment: which button field get disabled

Comment: It's random, when I click the boxes in the listView in midway, the bottom one's get disabled

Comment: you have used the same `if(position<mButtonSelected)` in your code and remove `@Override
public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
    return false;
}` try again

Comment: this `@Override
public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
    return false;
}` code creates the issue remove this from your code. This will solve your problem see [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html)

Comment: The override did work, but there was another condition to be passed. I am editing the whole code in my question for the resolution.
Thanks again!

Comment: Dude try atleast once by removing `areAllItemsEnabled()` method from you code

Comment: Dude, I did apply it, and it helped. Thanks for that. I'm just altering the code, and will upload it in some time.

Answer (score 0):

Get the position of the row which is clicked and then set onclick false for positions less than clicked position

as follows:

```
viewHolder.txtStnArr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.e("Position: " , String.valueOf(position)); 
            for (int i = 0; i < position; i++) {
                  viewHolder.txtStnArr.setEnable(false);
             }
             notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Here, I am getting the position of the row which is clicked. 

viewHolder.txtStnArr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.e("Position: " , String.valueOf(position));
            }
        });


Where should I put the onClick false for all the above fields?

Comment: In the same listener by using for loop